# eks create cluster command fails with Error: computing fingerprint illegal base64 data at input byte 11

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am trying to create a kubernetes cluster using EKS. The command I am using is

```
eksctl create cluster --name prod --version 1.14 --region us-west-2 --nodegroup-name standard-workers --node-type t3.medium --nodes 3 --nodes-min 1 --nodes-max 4 --ssh-access --ssh-public-key <pathto>/certificate.pem --managed
```

The certificate.pem above is the x.509 certificate that I downloaded from AWS Console "My security credentials" page.
The command throws an error:

```
Error: computing fingerprint for key "/Users/xxxx/work/tech/aws/certificate.pem": error decoding SSH public key: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDhjCCAm6gAwIBAgIVAKuhOc5Vbrgl7Y3ZfxBAj9uY9aeDMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB\nBQUAMFMxITAfBgNVBAMMGEFXUyBM
```

-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" err: illegal base64 data at input byte 11

what is the ssh-public-key eksctl is expecting here?

Comment: You just need to specify the KeyName without .pem.

Answer (score 11):

Got it. The certificate format is not what eksctl likes. Ended up converting the private_key.pem downloaded from AWS and converted it to ssh pub key format using command:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f private_key.pem > public_key.pem
```

Comment: Need to make sure to rerun  `sudo chmod 700 kube-demo.pem` after converting

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the [documentation of eksctl](https://eksctl.io/introduction/) for this matter. As clearly documented, you have **two** options.

**SSH Access**

In order to allow SSH access to nodes, `eksctl` imports `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` by default, to use a different SSH public key, e.g. `my_eks_node_id.pub`, run:

```
eksctl create cluster --ssh-access --ssh-public-key=my_eks_node_id.pub
```

> This is the method suggested by the other answer.

To use a pre-existing EC2 key pair in `us-east-1` region, you can specify key pair name (which must not resolve to a local file path), e.g. to use `my_kubernetes_key` run:

```
eksctl create cluster --ssh-access --ssh-public-key=my_kubernetes_key --region=us-east-1
```

> Since you are using a key-pair stored inside aws, you can use this
> method. This is the easy way and you do not need to have the file in
> local machine.

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your issue-
just create key-pair in same regin where you have created your cluster.
Two things to consider.

1. When you created EC2 Key pair using AWS Management console in which region you have created make a note of it (Example: us-east-1)
2. When you first created your cluster, ensure the same region where you created the EC2 Key pair and cluster are in same region
   eksctl create cluster --name=eksdemo1 \                       --region=us-east-1 \                       --zones=us-east-1a,us-east-1b \                       --without-nodegroup
3. We really dont need to worry about the keypair we downloaded, AWS CLI and eksctl CLI will take care of keypair you created in AWS to reference when creating EC2 VMs for EKS. The key downloaded to our local deskop has no importance.